# jQuery Modal Box to gray over silverlight object?

Tags: jquery, silverlight

I have a silverlight control on an html page in which I would like the modal popup to also affect.

The whole page is white, including the silverlight app (bordered in red below). Is there some form of css or javascript to gray out the silverlight app?

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6259/slapp.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6259/slapp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight (and all plugins) by default own rendering out their own screen real-estate.

If you'd like, you can go into "interleaving mode". In that mode Silverlight tells the browser how to render itself and the browser decided how to do that.

Set windowless=True as a Silverlight  param and that *should* solve your problem. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156(VS.95).aspx

Edited, windowless not windowsless.

Comment: When I set WindowLess=Tue, I loose the mouse scroll ability inside the silverlight application, is there any way around this?